# Power dissipation in AC RC circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, power

Can anyone help me with this question?

> A 20 A peak-to-peak 60 Hz current passes through a 0.01 µF capacitor which is in series with a 33 Ω resistor. What is the power dissipation?

I have attempted a solution of:

$I_{rms}=\frac {I_{pk}}{\sqrt 2} $

$P_{av}=I_{rms}^2(R)=(20A)^2(33\Omega)=13200W$

However I haven't used all of the values in the question and considered it is an alternating current source

Could I use the impedance?

$Z=\sqrt {R^2 + X_c^2}$

Comment: you need to include the [impedance from the capacitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_impedance#Capacitive_reactance) as well

Comment: Impedance for a cap is $\frac{1}{j \omega C}$, where $\omega=2\pi f$ and $C$ is capacitance

Comment: So how do include it in the calculation for power? Thanks btw

Comment: you use $P=I_{RMS}^2(Z_{eq})$ instead of $P=I_{RMS}^2(R)$

Comment: Is that correct below?

Answer (score 2):

The only lossy component in the circuit is the resistor and the power dissipated in the resistor is $I_{\text{rms}} R$ so the conversion $I_{\text{rms}} = \dfrac {I_{\text{peak}} }{\sqrt{2}}$ has to be made assuming that the variations of current and voltage are sinusoidal.

The mean power dissipated in the capacitor over a cycle is zero.

Answer (score 1):

Power consumer and power dissipated will be different. Power consumed takes into account power supplied to the resistor and the capacitor. Power dissipation is the I^2.R losses due to heat. The power consumption of the capacitor falls on the imaginary axis. Hence we never observe it as heat.

Here's a guy asking a similar question: http://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/power-calculation-for-rc-cicuit.36890/

Comment: So it's just $P=I^2*R$ ?

Comment: For power dissipation, yes

Comment: So what is it then?

Comment: The current value depends on the impedance of the circuit. But the power dissipation will always be (Irms^2)*R

Comment: But doesn't it give you the current in the question?

Comment: The solution given in the OP is correct

Comment: @D.Jones one thing I just noted. You haven't used the RMS value in Power

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your answer is correct, except
You forgot to divide I by √2.

$P=I^2 Z$
$P=I^2 |Z| cos \phi$

$P=I^2 |Z |\frac{R}{|Z|}$

$P=I^2 R$

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform This is correct. Please check again in your book.
I have mine right in front of me now. It says cos phi R/Z.

Comment: http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/accircuits/series-circuit.html

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform  How come Z is complex no. I gave a link which says same. All my books say it.

Comment: An interesting debate which perhaps shows that the problem can be approached from two different ways.  One using complex numbers and the other not using complex numbers.  I think that you are both right.